# Расположение элементов по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать такой функционал. Есть список со статьями, изначально они расположены как блоки, но при клике на кнопку "Список", нужно чтобы данные блоки расположились списком

Внизу прикреплены картинки как пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не претендую на галочку, просто хочу сверстать :)

```js
$('.news-header .button').on('click', function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('--grid')) {
    $(this).removeClass('--list').addClass('--grid');
    $('.news').removeClass('--grid').addClass('--list');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('--grid').addClass('--list');
    $('.news').removeClass('--list').addClass('--grid');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f7f7f8;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.news-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.news-header .title {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #7c7c7c;
}

.news-header .button {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.news-header .button::before,
.news-header .button::after {
  display: inline-block;
}

.news-header .button::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 20px auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.news-header .button::after {
  color: #216cc8;
}

.news-header .button.--list::before {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/RZSOJ7w.png');
}

.news-header .button.--list::after {
  content: 'Списком';
}

.news-header .button.--grid::before {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/pgIDCFB.png');
}

.news-header .button.--grid::after {
  content: 'Плиткой';
}

/* Общая настройка */
.news {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%; 
}

.news .item {
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
}

.news .item .image {
  display: flex;
}

.news .item .image > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 0;
}

.news .item .info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.news .item .info > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.news .item .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.news .item .date {
  color: #6f6f6f;
}

/* Стили для "Плиткой" */
.news.--grid {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.news.--grid .item {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc((100% - 30px) / 4);
}

.news.--grid .item:not(:nth-child(4n+4)) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.news.--grid .item:not(:nth-last-child(-n+4)) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.news.--grid .item .image {
  height: 20vw;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.news.--grid .item .info {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

/* Стили для "Списком" */
.news.--list {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.news.--list .item {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.news.--list .item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.news.--list .item .image {
  width: auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.news.--list .item .info {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.news.--list .item .info .date {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.news.--list .item .info .des {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="news-header">
    <div class="title">Общество</div>
    <div class="button --list"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="news --grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M1O6miS.png">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="title">10 причин приехать отдыхать в Бурятию на отпуск</div>
        <div class="des">Рассказываем о главных особенностях Бурятии</div>
        <div class="date">12 Мая 2020</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Kcqipsd.png">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="title">Как будут развиваться пункты пропуска в Приморье</div>
        <div class="des">Самое главное о том, в каких условиях будем жить в июне</div>
        <div class="date">10 Мая 2020</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6jU1lzJ.png">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="title">Как дистанционно оформить пособие по безработице</div>
        <div class="des">Дальневосточники получат государственную поддержку</div>
        <div class="date">4 Мая 2020</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7vlU4D2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="title">Подготовку к парадам Победы возобновили на Дальнем Востоке</div>
        <div class="des">Шествие состоится в день празднования ВМФ России</div>
        <div class="date">13 Мая 2020</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: эх...галка потеряна....как теперь жить....я думал краткость сестра таланта и не стал верстать...а оно вон как обернулось... (шутка)  ;)

Comment: @DmitriiSedov, сам не ожидал, просто хотел сверстать.. Прошу прощения)

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать таким образом, просто меняет `display` на другое значение, и далее добавляем зависимость дочерних элементов, от нового класса `active` который добавляется родителю

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('active'))
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container.active {
  display: block;
}

.container.active .item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.container.active .photo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
}

.photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="photo black"></div>
    <div>текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="photo red"></div>
    <div>текст2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="photo blue"></div>
    <div>текст3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>click!</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, данное решение подходит)

Comment: @ДмитрийМоисеев пожалуйста =)